# not able to understand the working of static concept here in

Tags: java, c++, static

I have java code:

```java
public class Test1
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
    t();t();t();
 }
 public static void t()
 {
   int i=0;
   i++;
   System.out.println(i);
 }
}
```

this gives output :

```
1 
1 
1
```

which I am not able to match with this C++ code:

```cpp
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int static t();
  int main()
  {
   t();
   t();
   t();
  }
  int  static t()
  {
   int i = 0;
   i++;
   cout<<i;
  }
```

This also gives

```
1
1
1
```

I thought (as in the Java case) one static `main` has one static method `t()` associated with it.

But as you can see, in C++ `main` is not static, so I am a bit confused about how the C++ code is giving the same output as Java, even though there is no static main. Doesn't that affect the way it works?

Or a more precise question would be: How is the `static` thing working here (in both codes)? A relative comparison would be enough for me.

Comment: `static` keyword doesn't have the same meaning in all languages. In Java, when the JVM calls the main method, there is no object existing for the class being called, so it has to be `static` in order to allow this from class.

Comment: what output would you like to see ?

Comment: you're basically asking "Why does `10 GOTO 10` in Basic produce an infinite loop, and only a syntax error in [any other language]?". You're comparing Java to C++, which is comparing Apples to Elephants.

Comment: Do you know that `i` inside method `t` is a local variable and because they are not static in nature and is only visible inside the method itself, it will always start at `0`.

Comment: Don't try to compare languages. If you are interested first learn on language to a little depth. Then see other languages. This will help understanding the second one more easily.

Comment: Reading about it [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/) the meaning of  `static` in C++ does seem aligned with Java's.

Comment: nice link..got to know many things... @MarkoTopolnik

Comment: Actually, I think this is *not* a static C++ class method. It's actually a C static function, because the C++ code doesn't actually define a class, hence both `main` and `t` are just functions, not methods.

Comment: for all the dis-likers of my question...i was comparing languages like that because i have to to.i was going through PPL(programming languages) study on various languages .so i was confused regarding main being static in java and non-static in c/c++

Comment: @RealSkeptic Good point, then this description applies: "When used at file level (outside of a function), it sets the visibility of the item it's applied to. Static items are not visible outside of their compilation unit (e.g., to the linker). Their duration is the same as the duration of the program." In OP's case, the `static` keyword isn't really making a difference.

Comment: Just to make this clear, static has absolutely nothing to do with your current  output. you keep setting i to 0, then incrementing it, then displaying the value, which is 1 every single time you call the function in either language. it wouldn't matter whether your functions are static or not in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, a static method is associated with the class and may be called without an instance. And therefore cannot access instance variables either.

In c++, static keyword has several meanings depending on context. A static member function (which is what class methods are typically called in c++) is quite similar to static methods in Java in respect of the above description.

However, neither `int main()` nor `int  static t()` is a member function at all. They're free functions, not associated with any class. Declaring a free function static gives it internal linkage. Which means that it will not be visible to functions in other compilation units (.cpp files).

The functions being static or non-static affects in no way how `t()` works in either version of your code. You always print a local variable and increment it. Since the variable does not have static storage duration (another use for the keyword static) nor is it a member of an object instance, but an automatic local variable, it is destroyed as soon as the function call ends and therefore the incremented value is never used for anything. On the other hand, if the *variable* was declared static, then you'd get output "1 2 3".

In Java, there is no free functions nor local variables with static storage duration.

Comment: I have a hunch that OP is actually aiming for `static int i = 0;` inside the C++ function. That would provide the difference he is expecting.

Comment: actually your hunch is somewhat correct.  i was thinking of that code too in this question but then i thought first let's compare these 2 codes...in that case you will see  output as 1 2 3

Answer (score 1):

The entry point requirements for Java and CPP are different. Java requires main to be *static* which serves as an entry point.

don't compare *languages in this way*.

Also, the value of `i` will always be `1` because it is a method *local* variable. Making `i` static would give you different results.

Comment: but why is java main required to be static? if entry point condition of java is  to have main static then why not c++/c can have static main?any link for reference would be fine..  @TheLostMind

Comment: Because that's how java was designed. The way the main method is found and invoked are different in C++ and java.

Comment: is this variation in calling of main has to do something  with oop features of java applied differently in both of these languages.

Comment: @SUMITKUMARSINGHDIXIT - Well kind of.. A static method is associated with the class and not with an instance. So to call the main method without creating a class, you have to make it static in java

Comment: oohh..so that's how you are able to call main defined in the same class from the same class.i.e by making it static ...

Comment: In C++, the `main` function is top-level (does not belong to a class). If the `main` function was declared `static`, that would make it invisible to the linker (it would be module-internal). I suppose that would not be legal for the application entry point.